Lenz Law Question?
Consider the following,

I am having trouble understanding how to calculate the magnitude of the induced emf between the axle and rim. Firstly, I know that by Faraday's law of electromagnetic induction, the induced emf is equal to the rate of change of magnetic flux. As the disc rotates in the magnetic field, the magnetic flux through the disc remains the same at all times, so where is the flux cutting?
Assuming that the time for one rotation is one second, why is the magnitude of the induced emf equal to the magnetic flux? Suppose I consider one part of the disc, vertically upwards, rotating through the field, it goes from being parallel to the field, perpendicular to the field and back to its original position after 1 second. So how is the overall change in magnetic flux in one second just the magnetic flux?
Secondly, according to Lenz Law, a current will be induced to oppose the change that caused it. So the current in the disc goes from the rim to the axle, but depending on which section of the disk you consider, won't the magnetic field because of this current act in various directions?
I am confused about how to apply Faraday's Law in the context of a disk that is rotating. I have done problems with looped wires rotating themselves to the field, but this one is confusing.

Read section 2 from this part of Feynman's lectures. This also appears in Griffith's book on electrodynamics (chapter on electrodynamics, actually). In this kind of situation, an emf appears even though there is no change in flux because of the Lorentz force, it's a motional emf. Consider one of the charges that is part of the disc, $q$, rotating around the axle. It has a velocity $r\omega$ where $r$ is the distance from the center to it. Then, the Lorentz force is $F=qr\omega B$. Now, this is the magnitude of the force. Vectorially
$$\vec{F}=q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}=q(\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r})\times\vec{B} = q((\vec{\omega}\cdot\vec{B}) \vec{r}-(\vec{r}\cdot\vec{B})\vec{\omega})=q\omega B \vec{r},$$
assuming $\vec{\omega}$ and $\vec{B}$ are parallel. The motional emf can be calculated as a line integral of force per unit charge
$$\mathcal{E}=\int \vec{f} \cdot d\vec{r} = \omega B\frac{R^2}{2}.$$
